# Why zero article is used here

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

I came upon this sentence in a book I was reading ("Why Aren't They Shouting?" by Kevin Rogers):

> (...) it is always pored over by banks and their regulators for months after publication.

Why is there no article before "publication"? It seems to me that it should be "the publication".

Answer (score 2):

"Publication" is a mass noun here, meaning bringing a material into print or online. It doesn't need an article, and when the zero article is used, the context makes it clear what is being referred to. Otherwise, you can use "the publication of..."

You have three ways of saying the same thing:

> The book hasn't been reviewed after publication.
>
> After its publication, the book has been targeted by critics.
>
> Since the publication of her book, she has received tons of emails.